Mutate columns based on filtered rows
I have data structured like this:
Location    Sample      HeV NiV CedV GhV MenV Mock `Total Events`
74(1,B10)   FSS27681    93  100 93  94  169 96  2392
75(1,C10)   FSS26893    108 110 104 113 137 100 2084
76(1,D10)   FSS27851    100 91  96  160 129 79  3148
77(1,E10)   FSS27852    96  92  280 103 155 81  1982
78(1,F10)   FSS27854    182 124.5 163 400.5 234 92 2548
79(1,G10)   FSS27875    99  94  89  118 163 96  2094
80(1,H10)   Background0 100.5   103 94  97  123 108 1713
81(1,A11)   FSS28147    194 250 157 169 253.5   195 1978
82(1,B11)   FSS28148    82  91  133 139 192 84.5    2363
83(1,C11)   FSS28149    189 141 173 488 278 100 1991
84(1,D11)   FSS28150    143 106 145 365 189 108 2212
85(1,E11)   FSS27828    87  91  90  95  102 93.5    2119
86(1,F11)   FSS28051    73  79  74  84  84  76  2767
87(1,G11)   FSS27886    88  93  83  89  105 77  1768
88(1,H11)   Pos         1428    8472    86  90  107 90  1556
89(1,A12)   FSS28161    114 102 106 186 137 84  1915
90(1,B12)   FSS28165    2514.5  339 108 196 279 129 1906
91(1,C12)   FSS27986    104 90  152 137 127 75  2212
92(1,D12)   FSS28191    269.5   140 115 111 122 210 2207
93(1,E12)   FSS27894    104 90  107 159 110 85  2185
94(1,F12)   FSS28223    98  93  106 91.5    211 96  2085
95(1,G12)   FSS28426    86  91  94  84  168 82  2568
96(1,H12)   Neg         72  77  71  71.5    84  74  2598

I would like to filter() the rows that include Pos, Neg and Background0 and use those values to mutate() new columns.  The first value in the filtered rows would be paired with the HeV column and so on. It seems a bit confusing in text so I will post the data frame that I am trying to achieve.
Location    Sample  HeV HeV_Pos HeV_Neg HeV_Background0 NiV NiV_Pos NiV_Neg NiV_Background0 CedV    GhV MenV    Mock    Total Events
74(1,B10)   FSS27681    93  1428    72  100.5   100 8472    77  103 93  94  169 96  2392
75(1,C10)   FSS26893    108 1428    72  100.5   110 8472    77  103 104 113 137 100 2084
76(1,D10)   FSS27851    100 1428    72  100.5   91  8472    77  103 96  160 129 79  3148
77(1,E10)   FSS27852    96  1428    72  100.5   92  8472    77  103 280 103 155 81  1982
78(1,F10)   FSS27854    182 1428    72  100.5   124.5   8472    77  103 163 400.5   234 92  2548
79(1,G10)   FSS27875    99  1428    72  100.5   94  8472    77  103 89  118 163 96  2094
81(1,A11)   FSS28147    194 1428    72  100.5   250 8472    77  103 157 169 253.5   195 1978
82(1,B11)   FSS28148    82  1428    72  100.5   91  8472    77  103 133 139 192 84.5    2363
83(1,C11)   FSS28149    189 1428    72  100.5   141 8472    77  103 173 488 278 100 1991
84(1,D11)   FSS28150    143 1428    72  100.5   106 8472    77  103 145 365 189 108 2212
85(1,E11)   FSS27828    87  1428    72  100.5   91  8472    77  103 90  95  102 93.5    2119
86(1,F11)   FSS28051    73  1428    72  100.5   79  8472    77  103 74  84  84  76  2767
87(1,G11)   FSS27886    88  1428    72  100.5   93  8472    77  103 83  89  105 77  1768
89(1,A12)   FSS28161    114 1428    72  100.5   102 8472    77  103 106 186 137 84  1915
90(1,B12)   FSS28165    2514.5  1428    72  100.5   339 8472    77  103 108 196 279 129 1906
91(1,C12)   FSS27986    104 1428    72  100.5   90  8472    77  103 152 137 127 75  2212
92(1,D12)   FSS28191    269.5   1428    72  100.5   140 8472    77  103 115 111 122 210 2207
93(1,E12)   FSS27894    104 1428    72  100.5   90  8472    77  103 107 159 110 85  2185
94(1,F12)   FSS28223    98  1428    72  100.5   93  8472    77  103 106 91.5    211 96  2085
95(1,G12)   FSS28426    86  1428    72  100.5   91  8472    77  103 94  84  168 82  2568

I didn't fill in the mutated columns for CedV, GhV, MenV, Mock, Total Events for clarity. I tried some combinations of filter and pivot_longer but couldn't get anything to work. Thanks in advance for your help.

you can use bind_cols along with pivot_wider
dplyr::bind_cols(
  df |> dplyr::filter(!Sample %in% c("Background0", "Pos", "Neg")),
  df |> 
    dplyr::filter(Sample %in% c("Background0", "Pos", "Neg")) |>
    dplyr::select(-Location) |> 
    tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = "Sample",values_from = HeV:TotalEvents)
)

